# Задачка javascript по объектам (города)

Tags: javascript

Не понимаю как написать код, который отберет и выведет из данного списка самые населенные города по убыванию числа жителей.

```
var countries = {
  'Япония': {
    city: 'Токио',
    pop: '38505'
  },
  'Индонезия': {
    city: 'Джакарта',
    pop: '  34365'
  },
   'Филиппины': {
    city: 'Манила',
    pop: '25065'
  },
  'Индия': {
    city: 'Дели',
    pop: '28125'
  },
  'США': {
    city: 'Нью-Йорк',
    pop: '21045'
  },
}

for (key in countries) {
  document.write(key);
}
```

Comment: `countries = Object.values(countries).sort((a,b) => +a.pop - +b.pop);`

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: countries.sort is not a function
    at window.onload